# Unexpected merge of robots.txt from different sites

Tags: sxa, multisite

In a SXA based multi-site environment, the values of the 'Robots content' (/sitecore/templates/Project/SampleTenant/Settings) fields are unexpectedly merged from two different site.

Let's say the 'Robots content' of **site A** looks like this

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /temp_site_a/
```

and the 'Robots content' of the **site B** like this

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /temp_site_b/
```

In this case, the **robots.txt for site B** would look like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /temp_site_b/
Disallow: /temp_site_a/

Sitemap: http://siteb.sc/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you configure a `SXA` site with a wildcard as `hostname`, the 'Robots content' of this site will be merged into the `robots.txt` of every site, tenant overlapping.

I'm not sure if it's a feature or a bug, but I definitely didn't expect it and it took a long time to find the cause of the wrong content in our `robots.txt`.